# Using PHP to remove xml duplicates

Tags: php, xml

i currently have 2 XML files exactly the same structure, i want to remove the entrys (or nodes) in XMLfile1 if they exist in XMLfile2. The structure i am using is below :

XMLFile1:

```
<ArrivingFlights>
    <flight>
        <to>Ciara</to>
        <from>Vikki xx</from>
        <imagepath>0003.jpg</imagepath>
        <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
        <time>11:00</time>
        <date>19/12/15</date>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <to>Eadaoin</to>
        <from>Dylan xx</from>
        <imagepath>0005.jpg</imagepath>
        <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
        <time>18:00</time>
        <date>22/12/15</date>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <to>Michelle</to>
        <from>Brianna xx</from>
        <imagepath>0001.jpg</imagepath>
        <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
        <time>17:00</time>
        <date>18/12/15</date>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <to>Ger</to>
        <from>Mammy xx</from>
        <imagepath>0002.jpg</imagepath>
        <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
        <time>08:00</time>
        <date>21/12/15</date>
    </flight>
    </ArrivingFlights>
```

XMLFile2 :

```
<flight>
        <to>Eadaoin</to>
        <from>Dylan xx</from>
        <imagepath>0005.jpg</imagepath>
        <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
        <time>18:00</time>
        <date>22/12/15</date>
    </flight>
```

In this example i would want to re-save file1 without the entry that you see in file2.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), the special purpose language designed natively to restructure XML files. You can even reference external XML files using  its [document()](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) function. Here XSL is loaded externally:

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl or .xslt file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Matches text between files and writes empty template (i.e. removes entire node) -->
  <xsl:template match="flight[. = document('OtherFile.xml')/flight]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script

```
// Load the XML source and XSLT file
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = 'Output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrivingFlights>
  <flight>
    <to>Ciara</to>
    <from>Vikki xx</from>
    <imagepath>0003.jpg</imagepath>
    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
    <time>11:00</time>
    <date>19/12/15</date>
  </flight>
  <flight>
    <to>Michelle</to>
    <from>Brianna xx</from>
    <imagepath>0001.jpg</imagepath>
    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
    <time>17:00</time>
    <date>18/12/15</date>
  </flight>
  <flight>
    <to>Ger</to>
    <from>Mammy xx</from>
    <imagepath>0002.jpg</imagepath>
    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
    <time>08:00</time>
    <date>21/12/15</date>
  </flight>
</ArrivingFlights>
```

Comment: Its writing all the nodes to the output file but it doesn't remove the duplicate.

Comment: Forgot to mention. You must save both XML files in same directory. It works perfectly on my end if your files look just as you pointed out. If not, please provide close to actuals. Does second xml have `<ArrivingFlights>` as root?

Comment: If so, simply change the xpath line in xsl file: `flight[. = document('OtherFile.xml')/flight]` to `flight[. = document('OtherFile.xml')/ArrivingFlights/flight]`

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it with Xpath query

```
  $message = null;
  $oldXml = new DOMDocument;
  $oldXml->load('xm11.xml');
  $option = array();
   foreach ($oldXml->getElementsByTagName('flight') as $product) {
    $option[] = '( to = "' . $product->getElementsByTagName('to')->item(0)->nodeValue . '" and from ="' . $product->getElementsByTagName('from')->item(0)->nodeValue . '")';//ArrivingFlights/flight[( to = "Ciara" and from ="Vikki")] your query format

  }
  $option = implode('or', $option);
  $newXml = new DOMDocument;
  $newXml->load('xml2.xml');
  $xp = new DOMXPath($newXml);
  $query1 = '/ArrivingFlights/flight[' . $option . ']';
  echo $query1;
  foreach ($xp->query($query1) as $product) {
      echo $newXml->saveXML($product);//delete it 
  }
```